# Convert an audio file into an array of samples

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I was wondering if there is a method of converting a .m4a audio file into an array full of samples. I am currently using the [Flutter sound module](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_soundf) to record the sound. The sound is the saved as a .m4a file with the  path `/storage/emulated/0/default.m4a`. Is there a way in which I can get the samples from this file in the form of an array. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using FFMPEG? Checkout this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32462384/split-audio-file-in-android). Then you could split your audio-file at whichever sample interval you desire and then store it in an array.